# How can I show that $f$ is bilinear and onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, bilinear-form

Let $\{e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n\}$ and $\{f_1,f_2, \cdots, f_m \}$ be the standard ordered bases for $\Bbb R^m$ and $\Bbb R^n$ respectively and let $\{E_{11},E_{12},\cdots,E_{mn} \}$ be the standard basis for $\Bbb R^{mn}$ appearing in some order. Consider the map $f : \Bbb R^m \times \Bbb R^n \longrightarrow \Bbb R^{mn}$ defined by $$\sum\limits_{i,j} a_{ij} (e_i,f_j) \longmapsto \sum\limits_{i,j} a_{ij} E_{ij},\ a_{ij} \in \Bbb R.$$

Is this map bilinear? Is $f$ onto? Our instructor suggests that this map is bilinear and onto. Suppose I take $(e_1+e_2,f_1) \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m.$ Then how can I show that $f ((e_1+e_2,f_1) = E_{11} + E_{21}\ $? I can't see how it is the case. Can anybody please help me in this regard?

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT** $:$ Every element of $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m$ can be written as $\left (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i e_i, \sum\limits_{j=1}^{m} b_j f_j \right ).$ So if $f$ acts bilinearly on such elements then we should have $$f \left ( \left (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i e_i, \sum\limits_{j=1}^{m} b_j f_j \right ) \right ) = \sum\limits_{i,j} a_i b_j  E_{ij}.$$

Now the question is whether $f$ is onto or not?

**RE-EDIT** $:$ I don't think $f$ thus defined is onto. For instance let us take $m=n=2.$ Let $\{e_1,e_2\}$ be the standard basis of $\Bbb R^2.$ Let $E_{11} = (1,0,0,0), E_{12} = (0,1,0,0), E_{21} = (0,0,1,0)$ and $E_{22} = (0,0,0,1).$ Now any element of $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2$ is of the form $((x,y),(z,w)),$ $x,y,z,w \in \Bbb R.$ Then by the definition of $f$ it follows that $$f((x,y),(z,w)) = (xz,xw,yz,yw).$$ This is clearly not onto since there does not exist any element in $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2$ which maps to $(1,2,3,4) \in \Bbb R^4$ under $f.$

Can anybody please check my argument above? Thanks.

If my argument above is fine then the bilinear map $\otimes : \Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2 \longrightarrow \Bbb R^2 \otimes \Bbb R^2 \cong \Bbb R^4$ fails to become onto as well.

Comment: Did you post the same question twice?

Comment: May be it is due to some technical error. I have deleted one of them.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy sir I think one cannot always write every element of $\Bbb R^{mn}$ as a $\Bbb R$ linear combination of $(e_i,f_j).$ For instance we could take $m = 1$ and $n=2.$ Then $\dim (\Bbb R^m \times \Bbb R^n) = m + n = 3 \gt 2 = mn.$

Answer (score 1):

The equality $(e_1+e_2,f_1)=(e_1,0)+(e_2,f_1)$ should solve your problems. This is true due to the algebraic properties of $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m$.

---

There does seem to be something wrong with the map $f$ as it is written down in your post. There are no $E_{ij}$ basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$. You have taken the standard basis $\{E_1,\ldots,E_{nm}\}$. So a good map would be $$\sum_{i\leq n}a_i(e_i,0)+\sum_{j\leq m}b_j(0,f_j)\mapsto \sum_{i\leq n} a_i E_i+\sum_{j\leq m} b_jE_{j+n}. $$

Comment: Is the map $f$ well-defined first of all? See we cannot always define it on whole of $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m.$ For instance take $m = 1$ and $n = 2.$ Then can you able to write every element of $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m$ as a $\Bbb R$-linear combination of two vectors?

Comment: The map $f,$ I am referring to here.

Comment: Yes. For your example: $$((a,b),c)) = a((1,0),0)+ b((0,1),0)+c((0,0),1).$$ Note that each of these vectors is in $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$. E.g $((1,0),0))$ corresponds to $E_1$.

Comment: Okay, there *does* seem to be something wrong with the map as defined above. Namely that $E_{ij}$ are not basis vectors as you have defined them. I'll add an edit to my answer.

Comment: Note that the map in my edit is not bilinear... But you are correct that the map $f$ you were given is not well-defined. In multiple ways even. First of all, the left hand side is, as you picked up, not a correct way to write each vector in the Cartesian product, and the right hand side uses $E_{ij}$ which aren't even defined at all.

Comment: $E_{ij}$'s are standard basis vectors of $\Bbb R^{mn}.$

Comment: @Phibetakappa it makes no sense to have a double index over that basis. Look at how you defined the standard basis in your post. $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$ is just all $nm$ tuples.

Comment: Is there any way to make $f$ bilinear? Keeping in mind the construction of tensor product it reveals that we should map $(e_i,0)$ and $(0,f_j)$ to $\textbf {0}$ for all $i$ and $j.$

Comment: No I have made a typo. Now fixed it. Please have a look at it now.

Comment: @Phibetakappa I don't see any tensor products anywhere. I also don't see what $E_{ij}$ is supposed to be now.

Comment: What is $\Bbb R^n \otimes \Bbb R^m\ $? Isn't it isomorphic as vector spaces to $\Bbb R^{mn}\ $? We have a bilinear map from $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^n \otimes \Bbb R^m$ which is onto. Right? Can I somehow bring that structure here?

Comment: Think of $E_{ij}$ as a $m \times n$ matrix whose all entries are zero except the $ij$-th entry which is $1.$ There is a linear isomorphism between $\Bbb M_{m \times n} (\Bbb R)$ to $\Bbb R^{mn}.$ Now do you get my point?

Comment: This is the first time you have started talking about tensors in this entire post. If your question is about tensors then you have to make this clear. Anyone reading the post as you had done before would have interpreted $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$ as the $nm$ tuples. Especially given that you wrote a basis in terms of $E_i$... I suggest you make your questions more clear in the future. Adding the correct tags helps as well. I'm going to drop this question now. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118198/discussion-between-phi-beta-kappa-and-palebluedot).